# Implementing update a product in shopify api using shopify PHP api

Tags: php

I'm implementing *@sandeep shetty shopify api* to insert records into my shopify store.  I have implemented insertion completely and working fine for my store. I'm facing problem during update. I'm unable to update records that are being inserted in store. I'm updating records as per their id being generated by api after insertion.
Here is my code that i have written for update product.

Array that will pass as parameter in shopify api call.

```
$product = array
    (

        "product" => array
        (
            "variants" => array
                (
                    "price" =>  $cat['selling_price'],
                    "inventory_quantity"=>($cat['original_qty']!="") ? $cat['original_qty'] : 'Null',
                )
        )
    );
```

Code for update product.

```
$update = $shopify('PUT', "/admin/products/#{id}.json", $product);
```

Comment: It's not working for me. The code which you people have edited is same as i have written in master code. Need some other alternative.